# $f(s)>0$ for all $s \in S$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let $S = \{s_1,s_2,\dots \}$ a countable infinite set  and a function $f:S \to \mathbb{Z}$.

Assume that for all $0<x \in \mathbb{Z}$ there is $M_x, t_x > 0$ such that for all $0 \leq k \in \mathbb{Z}$ the number of $s_i \in S$ such that $f(s_i) = x$ where $i$ is in the range $[kM_x,(k+1)M_x)$ is exactly $t_x$ (independent of $k$).

Assume also that $\sum_{x \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}}\frac{t_x}{M_x} = 1$ i.e, the occurence rates relative to the space, sums up to ratio $1$.

This reminds me of the case of probability of $1$ but not really sure if probability is the correct way to go or should use combinatorics.

Can we conclude $f(s) > 0$ for all $s \in S$?

If not, can we conclude this for all $s \in S$ except finitely many?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\sigma_1=\langle 1,-1\rangle$. Given $\sigma_n=\langle r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_{2^n}\rangle$, replace $r_{2^n}$ by $n+1$ to get $\sigma_n'$ and by $-(n+1)$ to get $\sigma_n''$, and concatenate $\sigma_n'$ and $\sigma_n''$ to get

$$\sigma_{n+1}=\langle r_1,\ldots,r_{2^n-1},n+1,r_1,\ldots,r_{2^n-1},-(n+1)\rangle\,.$$

Thus,

$$\begin{align*}
\sigma_1&=\langle 1,-1\rangle\\
\sigma_2&=\langle 1,2,1,-2\rangle\\
\sigma_3&=\langle 1,2,1,3,1,2,1,-3\rangle,\text{ and}\\
\sigma_4&=\langle 1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,-4\rangle\,.
\end{align*}$$

Now concatenate the $\sigma_k$ for $k\in\Bbb Z^+$ to form a single infinite squence

$$\sigma={\sigma_1}^\frown{\sigma_2}^\frown{\sigma_3}^\frown{\sigma_4}^\frown\ldots\,,$$

and let $f(s_k)$ be the $k$-th term of $\sigma$. For each $k\in\Bbb Z^+$ we have $M_k=2^k$ and $t_k=1$, but $f(s)<0$ for infinitely many $s\in S$.

Comment: Can we find some relatively tight lower bound for the sequence $s_{k_i} - s_{k_{i-1}}$ where $s_{k_i}$'s are the subsequence of $s_1,s_2, \dots$ with negative values? i.e, does it have to be exponential? or can it be polynomial or even constant?

Comment: @Aladin: I don’t know: I thought about it just enough to see that a sequence like $\sigma$ could be constructed. I wouldn’t be surprised if the negative ones have to thin out exponenetially, but this is a bit outside my usual range, and I don’t at the moment see how to attack the question.